# Isomorphisms between sub division rings of degree $2$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, vector-space-isomorphism, division-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two isomorphic division rings, both contained in the division ring $C$, and suppose that $[C : A] = [C : B] = 2$.

Under which assumptions do we know that there exists an automorphism of $C$ that maps $A$ to $B$ ?

Comment: Do you assume finite-dimensional over the center?

Comment: @Kimball: In general, no, although I would be equally happy with an answer for that case.

Comment: In that case, $A, B, C$ are division algebras over their centers, and so their dimensions (as v.s.) over centers are squares, so they'd all have to be fields.

Comment: That is not exactly true, you could have two isomorphic quadratic extensions inside a quaternion algebra.

Comment: @CaptainLama Oh, right!  I use that case all the time.  I knew I should've thought about special cases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem may be helpful in some cases.